# PHP uploading multiple images and inserting into them into database

Tags: php

i want to upload multiple images using this code but i can`t  , i think it would be  by using for each but every time i try the errors come everywhere 
i want to insert the whole images paths in one column and after each picture ','
here is the php code

```
if (isset($_POST['upload_file'])) {
  $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
  if ($_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {
    $temp = explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_name = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
    $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $image_ext = pathinfo($image_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $image_path = '../media/file/'.$image_name;
    $image_db_path = '../media/file/'.$image_name;
    if ($image_size < '50000000') {
      if ($image_ext == 'jpg' || $image_ext == 'png' || $image_ext =='gif' || $image_ext == 'jpeg') {
        if (move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $image_path)) {
          $ins_sql = "INSERT INTO files (imgs_paths, date) VALUES ('$image_db_path', '$date')";
          if (mysqli_query($conn,$ins_sql)) {
              header('Location: index.php');
            }else{
              $error = '';
            }
          }else{
            $error = '';
          }
        }else{
        $error = '';
        }
    }else{
      $error = '';
    } 
  } else{
    $error = '';
  }
}
```

and here the html code

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image[]" multiple/>
```

Comment: how many inputs are you using on your html?  http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: it might be more than 100 pictures i want to make the user select all of them through only on input

Comment: For that many, I think you need drag and drop functionality. Try this: http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php

Comment: There's also: http://designscrazed.org/html5-jquery-file-upload-scripts/

Comment: 100 picture each allowed to be 50,000,000 bytes == 4.7GIGABYTES. Good luck with that! You may need to rethink this process

Comment: @riggsfolly it was just a number i put  but i`ll change it later :)

Comment: Your next question will probably require the answer -> Edit the `php.ini` and amend `max_file_uploads = 100` and `upload_max_filesize = 1G` and `post_max_size = 101G`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I still have the error so i searched for another code , it works but it add every img to the DB in single row , but i want to add all the images in only one record like '1.png','2.png','3.png' here is the code jsfiddle.net/w40w3goy  can you help me plz .

Comment: No. If you use other peoples code it is your responsibility to read and understand it. Or you could always _write your own code_

Answer (score 0):

You're right about using `foreach`. If you need to upload multiple, you'll need to use it. And it's as simple as:

```
foreach($_FILES['image'] as $i => $file){
    ///... other code
    $temp = explode('.', $_FILES['image'][$i]['name']);
    $image_name = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
    $image_tmp = $_FILES['image'][$i]['tmp_name'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image'][$i]['size'];
    ///... rest of code
}
```

<sup>*Since it's an array of images, you need to access each element. Notice how we're using the array index(`$i`) to access the current element in the loop.*</sup>

As [*@RiggsFolly stated*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328218/php-uploading-multiple-images-and-inserting-into-them-into-database/35328335?noredirect=1#comment58365138_35328335), you can also use `$file` in your loop as it is **also** the current element in the loop. (*Instead of `$_FILES['image'][$i]...`*)

Comment: Note `$_FILES['image'][$i] === $file`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'll chuck that in the answer too!

Comment: There is not much point doing `as $i => $file` unless you use `$file` it inside the foreach. Otherwise it may as well be a for loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly tis' early here, I need a coffeeeeeee

Comment: tis' late here I need my bed

Comment: i tried this code  and i tried a lot of edits on it but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: the code stoped on that if   
if (move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $image_path)) {}

Comment: @geeksamu `$image_path` needs to be absolute, not relative. change it to: `$image_path = getcwd() . '../media/file/'.$image_name;`.

Comment: @Darren  I still have the error so i searched for another code , it works but it add every img to the DB  in single row  , but i want to add all the images in only one record like 

'1.png','2.png','3.png'   here is the code   https://jsfiddle.net/w40w3goy/